# Mongoose Aggregate with Array of Objects in $lookup

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have following Collections:

```
Collection A:

{
    _id: 123,
    name: "A",
    amount: 2,
    some_other_information: "ttt"
}
{
    _id: 223,
    name: "B",
    amount: 2,
    some_other_information: "ggg"
}

Collection B: 

{
    _id: 123,
    name: "K",
    amount: 2,
    some_other_information: "fff"
}
{
    _id: 2,
    name: "L",
    amount: 2,
    some_other_information: "vvv"
}

Collection: D

{
    _id: 123,
    name: "test",
    items: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            a_id: 123,
            b_id: 1,
            c_id: 123
        },
        {
            _id: 2,
            a_id: 223,
            b_id: 2,
            c_id: 223
        },
        {
            _id: 3,
            a_id: 345,
            b_id: 3
        },
    ]
}
```

I want to aggregate Collection D with Collection A, with the `a_id` in the D collections in the `items` Array.

So that I have following output:

```
{
    _id: 123,
    name: "test",
    items: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            a: {
                _id: 123,
                name: "A",
                amount: 2,
                some_other_information: "ttt"
            },
            b: {
                _id: 123,
                name: "K",
                amount: 2,
                some_other_information: "fff"
            },
            c: {
                _id: 123,
                name: "A",
                amount: 2,
                some_other_information: "ttt"
            }
        },
        {
            _id: 2,
            a: {
                _id: 223,
                name: "B",
                amount: 2,
                some_other_information: "ggg"
            },
            b: {
                _id: 2,
                name: "L",
                amount: 2,
                some_other_information: "vvv"
            },
            c: {
                _id: 223,
                name: "B",
                amount: 2,
                some_other_information: "ggg"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried

```
    const x = await D.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "A",
            localField: "items.a_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "a_items",
          },
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                name: 1,
                items: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$a_items",
                    as: "ri",
                    in: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$ri",
                        {
                        $arrayElemAt: [
                            {
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$items",
                                cond: {
                                $eq: [
                                    "$$this._id",
                                    "$$ri.a_id"
                                ]
                                }
                             }
                            },
                            0
                         ]
                        }
                    ],
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
        }]);
```

But in this way it is not aggregated with only the `a_id`. It shows every item in A Collection. Not to mention that it doesn't include `c_id` (which is the same as `a_id`, but it is not required, so it can be null).

So I don't know what to try anymore. Would be very helpful if someone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$lookup` with collection A
- `$lookup` with collection B
- You can add more lookup if you want for collection C
- `$map` to iterate loop of `items` array
- show required fields in `in`
- `a` add a field and filter `items` from `a_items` and get matching element and get first element
- `b` add a field and filter `items` from `b_items` and get matching element and get first element
- same as you can add `c` if you want

```
db.colD.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "colA",
      localField: "items.a_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "a_items"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "colB",
      localField: "items.b_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "b_items"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          as: "i",
          in: {
            _id: "$$i._id",
            a: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$a_items",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$i.a_id"] }
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            },
            b: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$b_items",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$i.b_id"] }
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/awREjwKR2-w)

Comment: Hey it worked! I just have one more question. Is there a way where I can restrict which attributes to show in A (colA) ? Because currently it shows every attribute in the collection, and I want only name and amount.

Comment: add second $project stage at last and show your all required fields `{ $project: { "items.a._id": 1 } }`